# Table - connect multirow and multicol boundaries

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I am using `multicol` and `multirow` to add lines in certain spots in a table, and can't get the following lines to connect:

[image]

In the bottom left connection:

[image]

zooming in even further:

[image]

Solutions which keep the -1, +1, and the text within the table are preferable, but not essential.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{array,multirow,multicol}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Confusion matrices}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cr|C{15mm}|C{15mm}|@{}}
\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{Actual\\class}} & $ -1 $ & $ N_\mathrm{TN} $ & $ N_\mathrm{FP} $ \\
\cline{3-4}
& $ +1 $ & $ N_\mathrm{FN} $ & $ N_\mathrm{TP} $ \\
\cline{3-4}
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$ -1 $} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$ +1 $} \\
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted class} \\
\end{tabular}
\caption[Confusion matrix]{A Confusion matrix.}
\label{fig:confusion_matrix}
\end{table}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix; remove the first pipe `|` and substitute its use in `\multicolumn{1}{|C{15mm}|}{..}` as below.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{array, multirow, lmodern}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Confusion matrices}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}cr C{15mm}|C{15mm}|@{}}
\cline{3-4}
\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack{Actual\\class}} & $ -1 $ & \multicolumn{1}{|C{15mm}|}{$ N_\mathrm{TN} $} & $ N_\mathrm{FP} $ \\
\cline{3-4}
& $ +1 $ & \multicolumn{1}{|C{15mm}|}{$ N_\mathrm{FN} $} & $ N_\mathrm{TP} $ \\
\cline{3-4}
&   & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$ -1 $} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$ +1 $} \\
&   & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Predicted class} 
\end{tabular}
\caption[Confusion matrix]{A Confusion matrix.}
\label{fig:confusion_matrix}
\end{table}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: A nice work around. Any idea what should be done if I had a huge matrix, and the cells without borders were the minority?